# Spout open function issue with large xlsx

Tags: php

Spout open function takes ages to open a xlsx file containing 180000 rows.

am using spout to read excell sheets,when an xlsx file containg 180000 records ,the open process takes 25 mins.what is the possible cause to this issue,and what is the possible solution.N/B i have no control over the excel production .

i was using PHPExcel but was advised to use spout to avoid memory leaks

```
$callStartTime = microtime(true);  
        $reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createXLSXReader();
        $reader->open($filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

During the loading process, [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) extracts all the strings that are used in the spreadsheet. This may take quite some time, depending on the number of strings, as it requires some IO for reading a file and writing on disk chunks of 10,000 strings (so if you have 200,000 strings, Spout will write 200 files).

If you had access to creation of the file, I would have suggested you to use "inline strings" instead of "shared strings". But since you don't, there's not much you can do without editing Spout's code directly. But if you wish to do so, you can take a look at [this part](https://github.com/box/spout/blob/0f0bf648024040d21c6bd9930299265e8fc42550/src/Spout/Reader/XLSX/Manager/SharedStringsCaching/CachingStrategyFactory.php#L40-L51). You can try tweaking these values according to your needs and see if that works better.